# Ways and instructions to tell a user to intentionally miss a multiple choice question?

Tags: forms, user-expectation, multi-selection, quiz

I'm currently brainstorming possible solutions to this UX question. In a multiple choice activity (not a quiz/form), if a user correctly answers a question, before they move on to the next question, I want to encourage the user to still click on the wrong answers and see the feedback from the wrong answers, so they understand why the wrong answer is wrong.

**My first question** is placement of these instructions: 
I was thinking about putting optional instructions either before the question, or after the last multiple choice answer. The reason I suggest the latter is that these set of instructions are rather unique, and could possibly disrupt the natural user flow of reading a question and answering the questiion.

M**y second question** is about the actual contents of the instructions are a question mark to me. I was thinking:

1. Direct Approach: If you get the answer right, please also take a look at the other answers to see why they're wrong!
2. Subtle approach: Choose the best answer, but be sure to go through all the answers later!

I was also wondering in terms of user experience if it would make more sense to put these "instructions" after the user has successfully answered thee question, rather than before?

Comment: do you have any mocks showing your efforts so far?

Comment: Why can't you just show the wrong answers (or wrong ones and the right one) after user has answered?

Answer (score 2):

Instructions can often be embedded within how the interface and taskflow is designed. In this case, an intermediate state could be introduced where the question transitions from a "test" phase to a "learning" phase. During the "learning" phase, the user has the choice to explore the official explanation for each right or wrong choice.

[image]

Comment: That still doesn't involve the user actively clicking on the wrong answers though. I'm sure I would be happy to be presented as to why I'm wrong, but I'm not sure I would read them if I don't actively want to know. OP seems to be asking how to "force" this behavior, in a way.

Comment: It might depend on the user's willingness to learn. The system can force a step but wether the user learns from it or just skips it is uncontrollable. Unless there is some external force or policy affecting how the user interacts with the system.